# Multilevel xml using SAX Parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I want to make a list view from below xml file:

```
      <Menu>
    <Project name ="Desktop Application">
<name>Desktop Application</name>
<Description>This is some text.</Description>
<image>2130837532</image>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>PowerISO</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837555</SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>Microsoft Office</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837549</SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>Adobe Reader</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage> 2130837506 </SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>Vlc Player</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837587</SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>Picasa Photo Viewer</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837554</SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>KM Player</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837542</SubImage>
    </Sub>
    <Sub>
        <SubName>Cricket</SubName>
        <SubDescription>This is some text.</SubDescription>
        <SubImage>2130837524</SubImage>
    </Sub>
</Project>
```

and so on
but I have created one for main projects but after clicking one of that I want to display sub projects according to the main project.
I was not able to create second list which will show sub projects according to main projects.
I have done this using SAX parser.
Plz help me for doing this.

This is my startElement() method and I want that if project name is desktop application than the sub project of desktop application will be shown on listview.
I am not getting this.
Please help me!!

```
       public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    currentElement = true;

    if (qName.equals("Menu")) {
        subList = new ArrayList<SubProjectInfo>();
    } else if (qName.equals("Project")) {
        subProInfo1 = new SubProjectInfo();
        String gh = attributes.getValue("name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set a flag to true when startElement() is called for the Project with the attribute name set to Desktop Application
2. Set the same flag to false when startElement() is called for a Project with another name
3. As long as the flag is true and startElement() is called for a SubName element, save the text content of the element to your list view.

Comment: I just want to know that how the startElement method is working, I mean the flow of that method? D.R.

Comment: I think you haven't understood SAX. The startElement() is not called once for the whole document, this is not DOM. The startElement() is called many many times: once for each element in your XML! So you have to save state (i.e. the flag I talked in my initial answer) in your handler and follow the rules I described.